# What is the difference between User Logon name and Pre-Windows 2000 logon name during the User creation in Windows Server Active Directory?

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2

[image]

The New User Object creation window has two text fields, one for User logon name and other for User logon name (pre-Windows 2000).  What is the difference between these two logon names? What significant role do they play in Active Directory working?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The pre-Windows 2000 logon name is called the *SAM Account Name* and exists for compatibility with old systems (although it is still used very commonly in modern setups), it has a 20 character limit and works in conjunction with the domain NETBIOS name, in your example, `LZ` to give the Username`LZ\username`.

The other is the more modern version, has a much higher character limit and combines with the *user principal suffix*, usually but not necissarily the DNS domain name, in your example, `@lz.com` to give you the *User Principal Name* `username@lz.com`.

Despite similarities, these are not interchangeable and can be completely different.